# Inline css wont toggle, no javascript

Tags: html, css, inline

I am trying to achieve toggle of div using just inline css but its not working. please note that inline css is required no javascript. Thanks guys.

```html
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <a id="hide1" href="#hide1" class="hide">+ Expand</a>
    <a id="show1" href="#show1" class="show" style="display: none;">- Expand</a>
    <div class="details" style="display: none;">
      Content goes here.
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you use `javascript` too? Maybe inline `javascript`?

Comment: Hi no javascript, just css

Comment: Based on the sample you've provided I see no reason to expect it to toggle. What are expecting it to do, and why do you expect it?

Comment: I am trying to send this to an email, to mimic toggle of previous email content sent

Comment: I don't think this is possible. CSS is for styling content, and that only

Comment: it will be passed into an api, through the body.

Comment: Not possible with inline CSS. You will need a style block at the bare minimum. Inline style can only style the element it is on, **nothing** else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [summary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) / [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) HTML elements.

```html
<details>
    <summary>Expand</summary>
    Content goes here.
</details>
```

Comment: can we achieve this using inline style

Comment: You could do it with no css at all if you are okay with a little triangle. See edit.

Comment: TIL the existence of the `details` element

Comment: Wow your the best!

Answer (score 1):

Use a checkbox instead.

```css
input:not(:checked) + .toggle {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span>Show</span><input type="checkbox" />
<div class="toggle">Hello World!</div>
```